# Workaround for bug_id=4806603 regarding getBounds() and setBounds() on Linux?

Tags: java, linux

On the Linux platform, Frame::getBounds and Frame::setBounds do not work consistently. This has already been reported in 2003(!), see here:

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4806603

For convenience, I have simplified the stated code that results in a bug and paste it as:

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/** Demonstrates a bug in the java.awt.Frame.getBounds() method.
 * @author Mirko Raner, PTSC
 * @version 1.0 (2003-01-22) **/
public class GetBoundsBug extends Frame implements ActionListener {
  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    GetBoundsBug frame = new GetBoundsBug();
    Button button = new Button("Click here!");
    button.addActionListener(frame);
    frame.add(button);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
    bounds.y--;
    setBounds(bounds);
    bounds.y++;
    setBounds(bounds);
  }
}
```

**Unexpected behavior:** Upon clicking the button the window is shifted slightly below! (On my system by 28 pixels each click.)

Here is a screen recording: https://youtu.be/4qOf99LJOf8

This behavior has been around for 13+ years, so probably there won't be any change from the official side.

Does anybody have a workaround for this bug? Specifically, I would like to store and restore the window/frame/dialog at the previous location reliably on all platforms.

PS: My java installation is **jdk1.8.0_102** for amd64 by **Oracle** on Ubuntu 16 Linux. Since I recently migrated from Windows to Ubuntu, I know that on Windows, the code above works as expected.

The adaptation to Swing using SwingWorker produces the same effect:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class GetBoundsBug extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    GetBoundsBug myJFrame = new GetBoundsBug();
    JButton myJButton = new JButton("Click here!");
    myJButton.addActionListener(myJFrame);
    myJFrame.setContentPane(myJButton);
    myJFrame.setSize(300, 300);
    myJFrame.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    SwingWorker<Void, Void> mySwingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
      @Override
      public Void doInBackground() {
        Rectangle myRectangle = getBounds();
        myRectangle.y--;
        setBounds(myRectangle);
        myRectangle.y++;
        setBounds(myRectangle);
        return null;
      }
    };
    mySwingWorker.execute();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have jumped to a conclusion that a specific bug is what you are seeing.  The bug mentioned deals with running on top of the Enlightenment Window manager (e17) which was release 19 years ago, and doesn't even ship with Ubuntu 16 Linux (to my knowledge).

Comment: my system uses the window manager: Compiz

Comment: Then a bug specific to e17 doesn't apply to you.  Just like a bug specific to OSX doesn't apply to a Windows system.  The bug you reference is against the e17 windowing system, something I had a lot of fun customizing nearly 20 years ago.  Very, very few people use it now, and the reason it wasn't going to be fixed was that it was a dead project 13 years ago.  e20 is it's current release, but I'm not sure if it is stable yet.  To summarize, you misinterpreted the bug to apply to you, but it doesn't, it is 100% unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the original bug database entry this is marked as "Won't fix" and explained as a quirk in the window manager, rather than the JDK.

What window manager are you using?

Comment: window manager: Compiz. I have a similar issue with JavaFx which is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086597/first-call-to-javafx-stagesety-inconsistent-on-linux-workaround

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional note.  I noticed that your code failed to do very much on the Event Dispatch Thread.  All of Java's drawing APIs are single threaded by design, meaning that your application should not be expected to work correctly unless you dispatch GUI updates to the Event Dispatch Thread.

This means you need to (in your main) create a new Runnable that when evaluated will present your widgets, and submit that to the EDT.

Also, your action listener updates the component state within the action, bypassing the repaint request and ignoring the typical safeties required to ensure dispatch to the EDT.

In both of these ways, you code is not valid GUI code in a Java environment, and the bug that you identify may have nothing to do with your behavior, as your program is violating the GUI toolkit design before you even know if the bug impacts it.

Also, awt only wraps components.  If the components lie, then the lie trickles into Java.  Not much can be done about that (but I no longer think it's the primary thing to worry about).  If you don't like that, use Swing, which is a much more sane / stable environment.

Comment: I appended to the question a code adaptation that uses swing. There, I tried your advice by using SwingWorker but without success. Please advise, if I am using it incorrectly... thanks!

Comment: You need to pay attention to the tutorials about concurrency and Swing.  It applies to AWT too.  Here's the link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html